# How to avoid text in C++ to be outputted vertically?

Tags: c++, c++14

I need this to read a file and copy it into another file while modifying numbers, everything works except it copies and displays everything in vertical line. Is there a way how to avoid this? For loop seems to be a problem, but what should be added/changed without changing everything else?

Output should be:

```
9as 3
12as342sd
5678acv
```

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <ctype.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        string line;
        //For writing text file
        //Creating ofstream & ifstream class object
        ifstream ini_file {"f.txt"};
        ofstream out_file {"f1.txt"};
    
        if(ini_file && out_file){
    
            while(getline(ini_file,line)){
                // read each character in input string
                for (char ch : line) {
            // if current character is a digit
                    if (isdigit(ch)){
                        if(ch!=57){ch++;}
                        else if (ch=57){ch=48;}}
    
            out_file << ch << "\n";}}
    
            cout << "Copy Finished \n";
    
        } else {
            //Something went wrong
            printf("Cannot read File");
        }
    
        //Closing file
        ini_file.close();
        out_file.close();
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file? Please give us a sample of the current input and output.

Comment: `if (ch=57)` looks suspicious.  Are you compiling with warnings enabled?

Comment: if you add a `\n` after every character then there is a newline after every character. If you dont want that then dont do it

Comment: you're adding a newline manually here : out_file << ch << "\n";} - try removing the << "\n" part.

Comment: never use magic numbers like `57`. Use `ch == '9'` instead

Comment: File contents:
9as 3
12as342sd
5678acv

Comment: Indentation of this code is deceptive.  The line `out_file << ch << "\n";}}` is actually **in** the for-loop above it.  You are outputting a `"\n"` newline after each character.

Comment: You can replace `out_file << ch << "\n";` with `out_file << ch << " ";`. This will give 1 space after every print.

Comment: I need to print the same only digits should be increased by 1. 4 rows in the file f.txt = 4 rows in the f1.txt not just one row or line

Comment: Please consider using auto-formatter / beautifier on your code. There are them also online (just checked), you can copy-paste your code into one and the copy-paste back to your editor. It might make the problem clear. After that, try to keep your code formatted the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to split code to smaller pieces.

Take a look on that:

```cpp
#include <cctype>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

char increaseDigit(char ch) {
    if (std::isdigit(ch)) {
        ch = ch == '9' ? '0' : ch + 1;
    }
    return ch;
}

void increaseDigitsIn(std::string& s)
{
    for (auto& ch : s) {
        ch = increaseDigit(ch);
    }
}

void increaseDigitsInStreams(std::istream& in, std::ostream& out)
{
    std::string line;
    while(out && std::getline(in, line)) {
        increaseDigitsIn(line);
        out << line << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ini_file { "f.txt" };
    std::ofstream out_file { "f1.txt" };
    increaseDigitsInStreams(ini_file, out_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`out_file << ch << "\n";}}`

I don't know if I understand your problem fully since you didn't give any output, but looks like you should get rid of "\n" in this line. It makes a new line after each character.

Comment: It helps but everything shouldnt be in one line

Comment: What this code supposed to do?

Comment: Code should copy and paste it into other file while increasing all digits by 1

Comment: @Zero So when do you want it to have line breaks? Now you quite explicitly print line break after every `ch`... Print them when you want them.

Comment: There should be the same amount of line breaks as in first file, but i dont know how much. It could be 1 or it could be 100 line breaks

Comment: @Zero So sintce `std::getline` removes the line break, you need to print one after you handle each `line`, no?

Comment: @hyde Probably so.